# How to make sound fx follow the player?

Tags: camera, godot, sound-effects

Here is the setup:

```
> KinematicBody2D (Player)
- > Camera2D
- > Node2D (SoundFX)
- - > Timer (1 sec)
- - > AudioStreamPlayer2D (Beep)
```

It works fine at the beginning of the scene, but the sound fades out when the player moves away. Whyt is that and how to fix it?

I have tried to make the `AudioStreamPlayer2D` a child of a `CanvasLayer` node, without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have sound without attenuation, the simple solution is to use [`AudioStreamPlayer`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_audiostreamplayer.html) instead of [`AudioStreamPlayer2D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_audiostreamplayer2d.html).

The `AudioStreamPlayer2D` node is a `AudioStreamPlayer` with a 2D position. The maximum distance and attenuation curve controls how strong it sounds based on its distance to the screen center. The horizontal offset from the center of the screen is used for panning.

*And sadly, there isn't a `Listener2D` (no such node exist), that we could place on the Player. `AudioStreamPlayer2D` always work with the screen center.*

Of course, given the scene tree, I'd expect the `AudioStreamPlayer2D` to stay on the center of the screen. However, if the Player is moving away from the center of the screen (which depends on how the [`Camera2D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_camera2d.html) moves) or if the `AudioStreamPlayer2D` is moving relative to it, then you would have attenuation.

Thus, for a solution using `AudioStreamPlayer2D`, I'd suggest to make it child of the current `Camera2D`, so that it is centered on the screen (regardless of whether or not the player moves away from the center of the screen)… As long as you don't change current `Camera2D`, or move the `AudioStreamPlayer2D` relative to it.

For a more complex scenario, let us say you want the `AudioStreamPlayer2D` centered on the screen when the current `Camera2D` is the one on the Player, but centered on the Player when you are using another camera. To do that, we can put a script on the `AudioStreamPlayer2D` to move it. Give it the [`NodePath`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_nodepath.html) of the `Camera2D` and the Player. The script will check if the `Camera2D` is current, and if it is, set its own global position to match the `Camera2D`. If it isn't, then set its won global position to match the Player. *Note that this requires to always unset the current `Camera2D` when you set a new one.*